# Dont stort text with date headers parameters in JQuery tablestorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem whene im using this code:

```
function setTableSorterPager() {
$("#tableDocument").tablesorter({
     widthFixed : true,
     dateFormat : "dd/mm/yyyy",
      headers: {
        0: { sorter: "shortDate" }, //dateFormat will parsed as the default above
        1: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy" }, // set day first format; set using class names
        2: { sorter: "text" },

        // 3: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "yyyymmdd" }  // set year first format; set using data attributes (jQuery data)
        },   
     sortList: [
        [0, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 2],
        [7, 2]
    ],
     widgets: ['zebra']
});
```

I need the 3-5 and 6 colums with storter DATE, and the other ones with storter TEXT, but, the problems is when y use this code, only the DATE COLUMNS are fine, the other ones dont stort.

Thanks for your help!